# Receiving and Processing HEX data from Serial

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, serial-port

I'm new to this forum so I'm not sure if this is really the place to put this - feel free to move to a more appropriate forum if required.

---

Okay so I'm writing a simple application in VB 2010 that sends and receives HEX data to a serial device. Now I have the "sending" part down pat, however, I'm having difficulty with the receiving part.  The device sends a constant stream of HEX data back to the application every second; I need the application to look at certain bytes of the received HEX string and do things accordingly within IF Statements (e.g. If byte 10 of the string is equal to "&10" then do ... ).

I'm not sure how to get this data, parse the correct byte out of it and then do something with it. :/ The code I've attempted to use for this (but does not work) is as follows:-

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As     System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
       Dim statusget() As String
       Dim str1 As String
       str1 = SerialPort1.ReadExisting()
       statusget = str1.Split(",")

    If statusget(10) = "&01" Then
        btn_tx1.BackColor = Color.Red
        btn_tx2.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        btn_tx3.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        btn_tx4.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        btn_tx5.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        btn_tx6.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        btn_tx7.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        btn_tx8.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
    End If
End Sub
```

Additionally, I have a Rich-Text box that displays all data received from the device so I can monitor it.  It works fine, except for the fact that it returns in a weird encoding (not HEX) such as "uZ!!!??".

Thank you for any help you can provide. :)

---

**Edit - Code for Sending data:**

```
Private Sub btn_tx1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_tx1.Click
    Dim buftx1() As Byte = {&HF0, &H5A, &HF, &H5, &H1, &H11, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H30, &H37, &HFF}
    SerialPort1.Write(buftx1, 0, buftx1.Length)
End Sub
```

Comment: This might be totally off but it's worth a shot. It's possible that uZ!!!??? is a representation of the hex string. Say that you send AB as hex. That is 01010110 in bits which gives "V" as string result(ASCII). Try converting str1 to hex, it might work. If possible: do provide the code that sends data.

Comment: Hmm how would I go about converting the str1 variable to Hex then? I just updated the post with sending.

Comment: 1: Turn string to bytes: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/faq/dotnetstrtobytes.html
2: Turn Bytearr to Hex string: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharpgeneral/thread/3928b8cb-3703-4672-8ccd-33718148d1e3

Answer (score 1):

Avoid thinking about "hex" data, as hex is merely a way to format binary data into a string that's easy to read by humans.

Clearly, your device is using a binary protocol; your Click event handler is proof of that.  Which invariably means that it also returns binary data, not text.  Which makes using SerialPort.ReadExisting() wrong, that reads text.  The result of that is the garbage that you are now seeing, particularly the question marks.  Those are produced because it doesn't know how to convert the bytes it receives to ASCII characters.

You must instead use SerialPort.Read() to fill a Byte().  Be sure to pay attention to the return value of Read(); that tells you how many bytes you got.  The result will be less than the number of bytes you asked for.  Keep calling Read() until you get the full response from the device according to the protocol rules.

Once you got the full response you can then process it using the data that the device returned.  Displaying it in a RichTextBox is not terribly useful, other than for debugging purposes.  You can use the BitConverter.ToString(Byte()) overload to generate a hex string from the bytes.  Be sure to use Control.BeginInvoke() in your DataReceived event handler, as you cannot update the UI directly since the event runs on a worker thread.

If you need help with the protocol rules then contact the vendor of the device for support.

Comment: Hi Hans, thank you for your very informative post. This explains a lot to me regarding the data. Is it at all possible to give an example as to how I would implement this in my code (including an example if statement if possible?). My head is kind of spinning with all this new information and an example could be very useful in understanding this process better. :)

Comment: The only example code I could post would get you started the wrong way, I don't know the device protocol.